# Validate whether the first character in the textField is Uppercase and alphabet - Zend Framework 2

Tags: validation, zend-framework2

Is there any standard validation class for checking whether the first character in the textfield sis uppercase and alphabet, or one should write the own validator for this purpose, I have read the standard validation docs regarding [Alnum and Alpha](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html), but since my requirement is sort of specific, I wanted to get the opinions of the Zend Programmers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the `RegexValidator` or write your own.

The advantage in creating your own validator for this special purpose is that a. your code becomes more readable (using a `FirstCharIsUppercaseLetter` validator vs. reading the regex of a `RegexValidator`) and b. you can pre-define the default validation error message.

I'd probably create such a validator using the `AlphaValidator` to validate that the first char is a letter and then check if [mb_strtoupper](http://de.php.net/mb_strtoupper), applied on the first char, equals the original first char.

// Edit: For best usability, depending on what you're trying to do, a filter could also do the job (to ensure the first letter is uppercase). There's a `StrToUpper` filter that you could easily extend to only change the first char. Thus, in case the user forgets to capitalize his input, it's done automatically without having to review it.